# HTTP error code 405: tomcat Url mapping issue

Tags: servlets, jax-rs

I am having trouble POSTing to my java HTTPServlet. I am getting "HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL" from my tomcat server".  When I debug the servlet the login method is never called. I think it's a url mapping issue within tomcat...

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>faxcom</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faxcom/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

FaxcomService.java

```
@Path("/rest")
public class FaxcomService extends HttpServlet{
    private FAXCOM_x0020_ServiceLocator service;
    private FAXCOM_x0020_ServiceSoap port;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String testGet()
    {
        return "{ \"got here\":true }";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Consumes("application/json")
//  @Produces("application/json")
    public Response login(LoginBean login)
    {
        ArrayList<ResultMessageBean> rm = new ArrayList<ResultMessageBean>(10); 
        try {
            service = new FAXCOM_x0020_ServiceLocator();
            service.setFAXCOM_x0020_ServiceSoapEndpointAddress("http://cd-faxserver/faxcom_ws/faxcomservice.asmx");
            service.setMaintainSession(true); // enable sessions support
            port = service.getFAXCOM_x0020_ServiceSoap();
            rm.add(new ResultMessageBean(port.logOn(
                    "\\\\CD-Faxserver\\FaxcomQ_API",
                    /* path to the queue */
                    login.getUserName(),
                    /* username */
                    login.getPassword(),
                    /* password */
                    login.getUserType()
                    /* 2 = user conf user */
                    )));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//      return rm; 
        return Response.status(201).entity(rm).build(); 
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/newFaxMessage")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ArrayList<ResultMessageBean> newFaxMessage(FaxBean fax) {
        ArrayList<ResultMessageBean> rm = new ArrayList<ResultMessageBean>(); 
        try {
            rm.add(new ResultMessageBean(port.newFaxMessage(
                    fax.getPriority(),
                    /* priority: 0 - low, 1 - normal, 2 - high, 3 - urgent */
                    fax.getSendTime(),
                    /* send time */
                    /* "0.0" - immediate */
                    /* "1.0" - offpeak */
                    /* "9/14/2007 5:12:11 PM" - to set specific time */
                    fax.getResolution(),
                    /* resolution: 0 - low res, 1 - high res */
                    fax.getSubject(),
                    /* subject */
                    fax.getCoverpage(),
                    /* cover page: "" Ã¢â‚¬â€œ default, Ã¢â‚¬Å“(none)Ã¢â‚¬ï¿½ Ã¢â‚¬â€œ no cover page */
                    fax.getMemo(),
                    /* memo */
                    fax.getSenderName(),
                    /* sender's name */
                    fax.getSenderFaxNumber(),
                    /* sender's fax */
                    fax.getRecipients().get(0).getName(),
                    /* recipient's name */
                    fax.getRecipients().get(0).getCompany(),
                    /* recipient's company */
                    fax.getRecipients().get(0).getFaxNumber(),
                    /* destination fax number */
                    fax.getRecipients().get(0).getVoiceNumber(),
                    /* recipient's phone number */
                    fax.getRecipients().get(0).getAccountNumber()
                    /* recipient's account number */
                    )));
            if (fax.getRecipients().size() > 1) {
                for (int i = 1; i < fax.getRecipients().size(); i++)
                    rm.addAll(addRecipient(fax.getRecipients().get(i)));
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rm; 
    }
```

}

Main.java

```
private static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://andrew-vm/faxcom/rest/login");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            FileInputStream jsonDemo = new FileInputStream("login.txt");

            OutputStream os = (OutputStream) conn.getOutputStream(); 
            os.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(jsonDemo));
            os.flush(); 

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
//          Don't want to disconnect - servletInstance will be destroyed
//          conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

I am working from this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/

Comment: Does the get method work? Which url do you use to make it work?

Comment: By the way, you said it write there's no mapping to GET, but you're using POST

Answer (score 3):

You're making a major conceptual mistake. You're mixing [JAX-RS API](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jax-rs/info) with [Servlet API](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). With `@Path` you're basically registering a JAX-RS webservice. That the class happen to extend from `HttpServlet` doesn't make it automagically a fullworthy servlet. Then, you mapped it as an independent servlet in `web.xml` (such an instance would **ignore** all JAX-RS related annotations like `@Path` and so on!), but you didn't override the servlet API's `doGet()` method as per Servlet API guidelines. That explains the HTTP 405 error that the `GET` method couldn't be found when invoking the servlet's URL.

I'm not sure what you're trying, but provided that you want a JAX-RS webservice, not a servlet, then you should first be working through [this section](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/) of the tutorial you found. It describes how to configure and register the JAX-RS webservice in `web.xml`. Then, get rid of the `extends HttpServlet` from your JAX-RS webservice class altogether and remove the wrong mapping from `web.xml`.

Please also read the tutorial's guiding text instead of only blindly copypasting code snippets and changing e.g. class/package names here and there without actually understanding what you're doing.